# Determining the unique household in an column

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Name | Name_Partner | Startdate_relation | Enddate_relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Wilma | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| Wilma | John | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| John | Lucy | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Lucy | John | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Lucy | Ronaldo | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Ronaldo | Lucy | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |
| Kim | Angelina | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Angelina | Kim | 01-02-1995 | NULL |

I got a table with the above information (say Table “information_Client”). The table has unique client numbers instead of names, but for this example I made fictional names. I want to have a query where I can determine- the unique households. The table contains the relation in both ways and that means that you get the same person in column named “name” and “name_partner”. The UniqueHousehold column should always get the first person of column “name” if they have a relationship. I’m not looking for only the relationships which is not ended, but all. I want to show the unique households through the years/months. Is there a query for this in sql-server?

Expected result:

| Name | Name_Partner | UniqueHousehold | Startdate_relation | Enddate_relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Wilma | John | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| Wilma | John | John | 01-01-1990 | NULL |
| John | Lucy | John | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Lucy | John | John | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Lucy | Ronaldo | Lucy | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Ronaldo | Lucy | Lucy | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |
| Kim | Angelina | Angelina | 01-02-1995 | NULL |
| Angelina | Kim | Angelina | 01-02-1995 | NULL |

The code I'm trying to use is as this:

```
SELECT NAME, NAME_PARTNER, Startdate_relation, Enddate_relation, Load_DateTime
INTO #Customer
FROM
    Information_Client
;
WITH RowNum AS(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) AS Id
  FROM #Customer)

INSERT INTO Client
(      [Name]
      ,[Name_Partner]
      ,[UniqueHousehold]
      ,[Startdate_relation]
      ,[Enddate_relation]
      ,[Load_DateTime]
)
  SELECT
    C.NAME
    , C.NAME_PARTNER
    , COALESCE(HH.NAME, C.NAME) AS UniqueHousehold
    , C.Startdate_relation
    , C.Enddate_relation
    , C.Load_DateTime

FROM
    RowNum           AS C
    LEFT JOIN RowNum AS HH
        ON C.NAME_PARTNER = HH.NAME
        AND C.Id > HH.Id
```

What I'm getting is that I have multiple rows for one row --> because of the ID's generated. I want to have just 1 row like the table above

This is the result Im getting now:

| Name | Name_Partner | UniqueHousehold | Startdate_relation | Enddate_relation | C.ID | HH.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 | 29 | NULL |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 | 30 | NULL |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 | 6177 | 29 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 | 6177 | 30 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 | 6178 | 29 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 | 6178 | 30 |

Desired Result:

| Name | Name_Partner | UniqueHousehold | Startdate_relation | Enddate_relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Ronaldo | Kim | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1995 | 31-01-1995 |
| Kim | Ronaldo | Kim | 01-01-1998 | 24-07-1998 |

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. And also your current query attempt.

Comment: The expected result should be the column named UniqueHousehold (added it already in the table). I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Why does Kim appear in the `Startdate_relation` column?

Comment: I see. But how did you decide John instead of Wilma (same date)?

Comment: @jarth --> J comes before the W. Keep in mind that my table consists of unique client numbers, So I want to have the number there which is the first number of the relation it finds. Maybe it's confusing to say it, but if you have the logic for the name one, then I can change it to the number one. Im not so experencied with sql, so Im struggling a lot with it.

Comment: Edited my question with additional information. Is there someone who could help me with this?

Comment: If someone else has an answer for me, it would really be appreciated. Im stuck and cant seem to let it work with the answer of Kendle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify a unique household we need to include the 2 unique identifiers. So as to identify that 1-2 is the same as 1-2 we specify that the one which comes first in an alphabetical sort is put first. Here we use the names but the same principal would work with id's - as longer as we join them with concatenation with a separator and not numerical addition. We need to know the difference between A + BC and AB + C and between 10 + 20 and  20 + 10.

> ```
> create table t (Name  varchar(10),Name_Partner    varchar(10),Startdate_relation  date,Enddate_relation date);
> insert into t values
> ('John','Lucy','1995-01-01','1995-01-31'),
> ('Lucy','John','1995-01-01','1995-01-31'),
> ('Ronaldo','Kim','1995-01-01','1995-01-31'),
> ('Ronaldo','Kim','1998-01-01','1998-07-24'),
> ('Kim','Ronaldo','1995-01-01','1995-01-31'),
> ('Kim','Ronaldo','1998-01-01','1998-07-24');
> insert into t (Name, Name_Partner, Startdate_relation) values
> ('John','Wilma','1990-01-01' ),
> ('Wilma','John','1990-01-01' ),
> ('Lucy','Ronaldo','1995-02-01' ),
> ('Ronaldo','Lucy','1995-02-01' ),
> ('Kim','Angelina','1995-02-01' ),
> ('Angelina','Kim','1995-02-01' );
> ```

> ```
> select
>   name,
>   name_partner,
>   case when name < name_partner then concat(name,'-',name_partner)
>        else concat(name_partner,'-',name) end unique_household,
>   Startdate_relation,
>   Enddate_relation
> from t
> order by 3;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name     | name_partner | unique_household | Startdate_relation | Enddate_relation
> :------- | :----------- | :--------------- | :----------------- | :---------------
> Kim      | Angelina     | Angelina-Kim     | 1995-02-01         | null            
> Angelina | Kim          | Angelina-Kim     | 1995-02-01         | null            
> John     | Lucy         | John-Lucy        | 1995-01-01         | 1995-01-31      
> Lucy     | John         | John-Lucy        | 1995-01-01         | 1995-01-31      
> John     | Wilma        | John-Wilma       | 1990-01-01         | null            
> Wilma    | John         | John-Wilma       | 1990-01-01         | null            
> Ronaldo  | Kim          | Kim-Ronaldo      | 1995-01-01         | 1995-01-31      
> Ronaldo  | Kim          | Kim-Ronaldo      | 1998-01-01         | 1998-07-24      
> Kim      | Ronaldo      | Kim-Ronaldo      | 1995-01-01         | 1995-01-31      
> Kim      | Ronaldo      | Kim-Ronaldo      | 1998-01-01         | 1998-07-24      
> Lucy     | Ronaldo      | Lucy-Ronaldo     | 1995-02-01         | null            
> Ronaldo  | Lucy         | Lucy-Ronaldo     | 1995-02-01         | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23b9c2180a3834812ae3b9d00442c5fa)*

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but this worked for me. Thank you so much man!